# WPF RoutedEventHandler doesnt work with content

Tags: c#, wpf, routedevent

I have problem with c# WPF routedevent. This code works fine:

```
        MyLabel myLabel = new MyLabel();//MyOwn component
        myLabel.Oma += new RoutedEventHandler(myLabel_Click);
        GameArea.Children.Add(mylabel);//GameArea is UniformGrid
```

But when I put myLabel in ToggleButton's content, routedeventhandler(myLabel_Click) doesnt catch the Oma-event(I debugged that):

```
        MyLabel myLabel = new MyLabel();//MyOwn component
        myLabel.Oma += new RoutedEventHandler(myLabel_Click);
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton box = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton();
        box.Content = myLabel;
        GameArea.Children.Add(box);//GameArea is UniformGrid
```

So why do ToggleButton blocks my routedevent?

EDIT:
Code works fine, but it makes troubles, when I put myLabel in ToggleButton's content.
OmaEvent in MyLabel seems like this:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent OmaEvent =
EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Oma", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyLabel));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Oma
    {
        add { AddHandler(OmaEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(OmaEvent, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        CaptureMouse();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        if (IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
            if (IsMouseOver)
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(OmaEvent, this));
        }

    }
```

OmaEvent never raise, if I put it inside the ToggleButton. If I don't put it inside the ToggleButton, it works.

Comment: Can you please share the MyLabel class and the Oma event code?

Comment: Can you verify that `OmaEvent` is actually being raised when the label is placed inside the `ToggleButton`?  Set a breakpoint in your label's `OnMouseUp` method.

Comment: OmaEvent never raise, if I put it inside the ToggleButton. If I don't put it inside the ToggleButton, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Oma` event is not being raised because the parent `ToggleButton` steals the mouse capture in its `ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonDown` method, which gets invoked *after* your `OnMouseDown` method.  No other element will receive mouse events as long as the `ToggleButton` has mouse capture, so your label will not receive the `MouseUp` event, and your `OnMouseUp` method will not be called.

Set `e.Handled = true;` in your `OnMouseDown` method to prevent the event from bubbling up to the `ToggleButton`.  This will prevent it from stealing focus, though it will also prevent the button from working normally when the `MyLabel` within is clicked.  It's unclear what behavior you want in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your [RoutingStrategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routingstrategy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your custom `Oma` event may not match with what you're trying to do.

If the `Oma` event is a RoutedEvent set to `Direct`, and the `MyLabel` class is of type `UIElement` then you should be able to do something like the following:

```
GameArea.Children.Add(box);//GameArea is UniformGrid
GameArea.AddHandler(Oma, new RoutedEventHandler(myLabel_Click));
```